# Is there a way to import an outer package from other package in my project dir in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, package

I've read [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) in stackoverflow and almost understood python packages. I want to know is there a way to import an outer package from other package in my project dir.

project structure is like this.

[image]

I want to use functions of module A in main2.py.
There is no need to write the errors I get (because they are mentioned in links). **I want to know is there a straight way to import funcs.py of module A in main2.py? (without changing the structure of project)**
Cause I had the same structure in django and when in django project I use from app_name.module_name import func_name it worked, but not working here.
I also read [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71348782/python-package-import-error-import-error-relative-import-attempt-without-known) and found that I'm running a file separately in my example, whereas in django I'm not running that module directly and it is executing by manage.py file.

I also read [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075884/python-import-module-from-another-directory-at-the-same-level-in-project-hierar), but did'nt get answer.
My whole project is [here](https://github.com/mohammadpmf/python_packages/tree/main)

Answer (score 1):

The correct thing to do is to have package `A` installed in the current Python environment, as a regular package: that ensures replicability regardless of the exact directory in which "A" is placed.

Other than that, for Python, "A" will "look like it is installed" if the folder containing "A" itself is in the "sys.path" list.

So:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "<pathto>/understanding_python_packages")
from A import funcs
```

will just work. Note that it will load and execute `A.__init__` in the process: "A" will be treated as a package.

If you want `A.funcs` as a stand-alone module (as far as it does not depend in other things from "A"), you can add the "A" directory itself to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, ".../A")
import funcs
```

This won't load `A.__init__`.

Note that from the user perspective, `sys.path` is just an ordinary Python list, no hooks, or other special behavior attached - it could even be replaced by a whole new list instance. The `insert` method called above is ordinary list insert, and pre-pending new directories at position 0 give them priority.

Comment: Thanks. This solution is like solutions mentioned in the links. I am wondering is there a way to link the files to each other according to a files position like in html and css "../../abcd/css/style.css" and not using packages. because I understood when we use . or .. in python import, the python interpreter treats it like a package and hence, the errors related to packges start to show up. Anyway, the solution you mentioned works for me perfectly. Thanks a lot 

Comment: this answer is not using `.` and `..` which requires all folders to be part of the same package. You can use the "parent directory" marker `..`  if you resolve it as an absolute path before inserting it into `sys.path`. This however will make your setup fragile and depending on "from where" your program is called. The "absolute" method from pathlib can do this:  `from pathlib import Path; import sys; sys.path.insert(0, str( Path("./../abcd/A").absolute() )  )`

Answer (score 0):

You should Package your code using a simple [toml file](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#configuring-metadata)
Then, install it locally using `pip install -e .`

Otherwise, you can use absolute imports. In order for those to work correctly when running arbitrary files, you will need your Python path to include your package's root directory. when using vscode you can use the following launch configuration to achieve that:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/understanding_python_packages"
            },
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```